# Getting null after passing Content-Type json raw in body

Tags: c#, json, wcf

Service is like

```
    public ServiceResult<ForGotModel> ForGotPassword(ForGotModel model)
    {

            int errorState = 0, errorSeverity = 0;
            string message = string.Empty;
    // other works goes here

    return new ServiceResult<ForGotModel>()
        {
            ErrorState = errorState,
            ErrorSeverity = errorSeverity,
            Message = message
        };
    }
```

when I tried to run services from postman the output is null for one variable

```
public class ForgotResult
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
public class ForGotModel : ForgotResult
{

    [Display(Name = "Store Code")]
    [DataMember]
    public string StoreCode { get; set; }
}

[OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
     UriTemplate = "/StoreForGotPassword",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
     ServiceResult<ForGotModel> 
     ForGotPassword(ForGotModel model);
```

ForgotResult is inherited in other also

I am sending like Content-Type is application/json

```
{
"StoreCode":"44YLS1001",
"UserName":"vbn"
}
```

but for StoreCode I am getting the value and for UserName I am getting null

any suggestion that can help me?cca
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code uses `ForGotModel` but you've only shown `StoreForGotModel`. Do you have a different `ForGotModel` class?

Comment: Sorry for that. i forget to remove in this code spinet. and i am using same model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. 
just updated with [DataMember]

```
public class ForgotResult
{

[Required]
[DataMember]
[Display(Name = "User Name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```